# Prefix the values with a string, but do not overwrite the existing values

Tags: jquery

I need to add this the constant line `<b>References</b></br>` to my text area, but I cannot seem to get it write without overwriting the existing values.

For example, the user will type the text, but it has to be already a prefix line. Please see the following screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/GGRtvsIvIG6U

This is what I have tried, but it overwritten my existing text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#textarea').val('<b>References<b></br>');
});
```

Comment: So what is "textarea"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `$('#textarea').val()` to get the original value and then append the new one to it.

eg.

```
var original = $('#textarea').val();
var str = '<b>References</b></br>';
$('#textarea').val(str + original)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation:

```
var textarea = $('#textarea');
textarea.val('<b>References<b></br>' + textarea.val());
```